# Create space between left border of vertically aligned list items

Tags: css, list, border, space, navbar

I am trying to make a vertical navbar. I have used an unordered list, with a `border-left` propoerty, so that on hover, I can change the opacity/color of the border. The problem right now, is that this border appears as a continuous line across the list items. I want to include some space between the list items so that the borders are separated and one can make out which border belongs to which list item.

HTML:

```
<div class="leftNavbar">
            <span class="navLine"></span>
            <ul>
                <li>Introduction</li>
                <li>Whats new?</li>
                <li>Gallery</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftNavbar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 500;
    left: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
.leftNavbar ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.leftNavbar ul li{
    font-family: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
    height: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:100px;
    border-left:4px solid blue;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ATQ4Q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a margin to the list items. Something like `margin-bottom:5px;`:

```
.leftNavbar ul li {
    font-family:'Sintony', sans-serif;
    height: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:100px;
    border-left:4px solid blue;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ATQ4Q/1/)**

Comment: so simple! I'm ashamed ;|